# Questions about a broken vise

Tags: tools

I pressed a log into a vise, which resulted in the vise breaking (more precisely the "fix part", i.e the jaw which is on the side with the wriggle broke down.)

After some [research](http://shaddack.twibright.com/projects/machining_ViseRepair/), it seems to me that the only way of repairing it would be welding, which I do not want to do (I have neither the equipment nor the knowledge for that).

Questions:

- Can a broken vise still be used for something else, or should I throw it away?
- Did I do something wrong, or was the vise bad quality? -- it was brand new, used only once before. (Or, in other words: are you able to break a good quality vise, just by the force of your hands, if you tighten it too much?)
- If it was my fault (i.e. even quality vises are breakabe): how do you know until which point it is safe to tighten a vise?
- If it was bad quality: what to look out for, when buying the new vise?

Comment: You can do thermite welding with minimal materials and equipment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exothermic_welding If you already know how, go for it. If not, your chances of success are much lower than your chances of disaster.

Answer (score 1):

Most vices have a handle scaled to match the force they can apply. Never do them up with extra leverage in other words.

I've broken an old but good quality vice before, but by pulling against it with leverage rather than using its own handle.

If it's new and you used it as designed, take it back. I did when I snapped a G-clamp using its own handle and got a refund on that and the identical one I bought at the same time and wouldn't trust.

Comment: Thanks for the advice: I had used its own handle. So I guess the quality of the vice was not good enough. (They did not refund me, since I had thrown away the receipt. So I bought a better one, and this time I'll make sure to keep the receipt as well.)